# How to set data to calendar using recurrence rule

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting some data from server with following diffrent recurrence rule

```
"FREQ=MONTHLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTHDAY=29;COUNT=2
"FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1";
```

and I want to set data to my custom calendar using above rules. So
how can I set data using this rule. I have attached screenshot of  my costumed calendar.

[image: calendar view with dates]

Comment: And what did you try to parse it? Do you use EKEvents? Custom one?

Comment: I am using EKEvents, but it directly set on default calendar of iPhone. but I want to set data with custom one